# Почему IntelliJ советует мне сделать методы package-private?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

В коде есть геттеры/сеттеры, IntelliJ все время выдает warning и пишет, что `access can be private-package`. Но если я сделаю доступ `private`, то у меня в коде будут ошибки. Почему IntelliJ выдает мне эти предупреждения, она не видит что методы используются вне классов? И как отключить это в настройках?

Comment: Добавьте минимально рабочий пример кода, в котором ругается и следование рефакторингу которого приводит к ошибкам. 
И вообще, речь ведь про Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`package-private` и `private` это разные модификаторы доступа.

`package-private` - позволяет использовать данные методы внутри одного пакета, данный модификатор доступа выставляется по умолчанию, когда отсутствуют иные.

`private` - в свою очередь, разрешает использовать методы только внутри одного класса.

```
package mypack;

public class Main {
  void getString(){
    return "String";
  }
  private getPrivateString(){
    return "Check it";
  }
}
```

В данном случае метод `getString` доступен в другом классе данного пакета

```
package mypack;

public class AnotherMain {
  public static void main(){
    Main m = new Main();
    m.getString();
    m.getPrivateString(); // ошибка доступа
  }
}
```

Comment: Немного офф,но мне больше интересно почему идея генерирует конструктор с модификатором `public` и тут же выделяет его, предлагая заменить на `package-private` )))

Comment: это скорее вопрос к JetBrains, могу только предположить, что так как чаще всего используется public конструктор, генерируется именно он, а дальше уже работа анализатора